# Fabric.js: selection box after cropping image

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs, crop

On using Fabric.js 1.7.3, I have noticed an odd behavior when cropping images. Essentially, I have set the clipTo method in an image to display only a small square in the center of the image:

[image: The image's selection box still takes up the original size rather than the cropped size]

However, the problem is that the image's selection box still takes up the original size rather than the cropped size. When clicking on the image, I would expect the corners to be right next to the edges of the picture; similarly, the selection should only be activated when I click on the cropped picture.

A possible solution for this involves exporting the cropped part of the image as base64, removing the old image and adding the cropped version instead. However, this is rather impractical and feels like overkill. Is there a way in which I could simply adjust the selection box to respect the cropped size?

Comment: Please include what you accomplished so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on AndreaBogazzi's answer, here's my complete solution in which I override the _render method. Whenever I create an image, I add a "sizeMode" attribute to it which tells _render how exactly to paint it:

```
fabric.Image.prototype._render = function(ctx, noTransform) {
    /* This is the default behavior. I haven't modified anything in this part. */
    let x, y, imageMargins = this._findMargins(), elementToDraw;

    x = (noTransform ? this.left : -this.width / 2);
    y = (noTransform ? this.top : -this.height / 2);

    if (this.meetOrSlice === 'slice') {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(x, y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.clip();
    }

    if (this.isMoving === false && this.resizeFilters.length && this._needsResize()) {
        this._lastScaleX = this.scaleX;
        this._lastScaleY = this.scaleY;
        elementToDraw = this.applyFilters(null, this.resizeFilters, this._filteredEl
            || this._originalElement, true);
    }
    else {
        elementToDraw = this._element;
    }

    /* My changes begin here. */
    if (elementToDraw && elementToDraw.naturalHeight > 0) {
        if (this.sizeMode === BadgingImageSizeMode.CenterImage) {
            drawCenterImage.apply(this, [ctx, elementToDraw, imageMargins, x, y]);
        } else {
            // Default _render behavior
            ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw,
                x + imageMargins.marginX,
                y + imageMargins.marginY,
                imageMargins.width,
                imageMargins.height);
        }
    }

    /* And they finish here. */
    this._stroke(ctx);
    this._renderStroke(ctx);
};
```

The drawCenterImage function I've defined is here:

```
const drawCenterImage = function(ctx, elementToDraw, imageMargins, x, y) {
    const sx = (elementToDraw.naturalWidth - this.width) / 2;
    const sy = (elementToDraw.naturalHeight - this.height) / 2;
    ctx.drawImage(elementToDraw,
        sx,
        sy,
        imageMargins.width,
        imageMargins.height,
        x + imageMargins.marginX,
        y + imageMargins.marginY,
        imageMargins.width,
        imageMargins.height);
};
```

While this works for centering images (as was my original question), different calls to ctx.drawImage will result in different effects. [Here is the documentation for the drawImage method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Comment: this._findMargins is not a function

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a function I wrote for fabric.js 1.7.3, which was the latest or at least one of the most recent ones when I wrote this question. The _findMargins() function was present in this version of the library - in fact, the call to it is in the part of the code I didn't even change!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it is still giving extra transparent space around an image.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no cropTo method in fabricjs.

There is a clipTo method that behaves as you described.

Cropping is not a basic fabricjs functionality yet. It will be probably made easier with the 2.0 release, but for now the only way to obtain it is subclassing the render method and do it by yourself completely.

- use the ctx.drawImage(this._element, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh) formula.
- mantain your own inforamtion for the crop are represented by sx, sy, sw, sh

Comment: Thank you! And apologies - I wrote "cropTo" rather than "clipTo"; I obviously meant the second one. I've already edited my question to reflect that.